# On back press, coming back to RecyclerView having Fragments causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, onbackpressed

I am having 2 fragments in activity. First fragment A has a recyclerview where one of the rows contains viewpager. This ViewPager has number of fragments (each page is a fragment) created using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Now clicking on an action item I am navigating user to fragment B. Here I am replacing fragment A by B using replace() method of FragmentTransaction. Now pressing back button on fragment B, application crashes with following exception:

```
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f110209 (com.example:id/vPager) for fragment VFragment{da512cf #0 id=0x7f110209}
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1800)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
02-06 18:21:49.038: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:957)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1541)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:502)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:176)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onBackPressed(ActionBarActivity.java:298)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at com.example.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:2049)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
02-06 18:21:49.039: W/System.err(6916):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
02-06 18:21:49.040: W/System.err(6916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-06 18:21:49.040: W/System.err(6916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-06 18:21:49.040: W/System.err(6916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-06 18:21:49.040: W/System.err(6916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-06 18:21:49.040: W/System.err(6916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Note that if I add fragment B using FragmentTransaction's add() method, then back press doesn't crash the app. From above crash log it looks like even before recyclerview has updated its views, viewpager child fragments are trying to find viewpager. How to prevent this or delay fragment state retaining process until recyclerview becomes ready again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into a similar problem (I was not using replace but I was using add), and I found a solution. You need to detach your nested fragments in either onCreateView() or onActivityCreated() for the parent fragment (fragment A). Then, in the bind call for that fragment you can re-attach. Here's some example code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nested_fragment);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Note that it is important to call executePendingTransactions(). If I understand the problem correctly, this is because onActivityCreated() is being processed as part of a FragmentTransaction. If you don't call executePendingTransactions it will continue to the nested fragments before processing the detach call.

Then in the bind call in your adapter, do something like this:

```
public void bindNestedFragment(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nested_fragment);
    if (fragment == null) {
        // Create/add fragment here
    } else {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction.attach(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

You'll have to give your Adapter access to the fragment manager through some means (I just pass it in the constructor). Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. I'll check after some time and come back to this post with the feedback.

Comment: Glad to hear it! It took me a while to figure this one out, so I figured I'd post my solution when I did.